# Magento - check if customer attribute already exists

Tags: magento, attributes

I have a custom module which is called on the `customer_save_observer_executed` event and specifically when a customer updates their details in their account page (name, password, email etc) I have added a custom attribute called display_name.

When a customer submits this form i need to check if the display_name currently exists for any other customer. If it doesn't then `setDisplayName(...)` else do nothing/display error message.

I was hoping to do this with this snippet:

```
$customer_check = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('display_name')
->addAttributeToFilter('display_name',$new_name)->load();

if ( is_object($customer_check) && count($customer_check) >= 2) {
    // dont allow - duplicate customer displayname
}
else {
    // allow update....
}
```

My current code in Model -> Observer.php

```
class xxxxxxx_Model_Observer
{
    public function xxxxxxxx(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        // to stop event being fired twice
        if(Mage::registry('customer_save_observer_executed')){
            return $this;
        }

        $postData = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost();
        $customer = $observer->getCustomer();

        // if updating NOT a new customer
        if($customer instanceof Mage_Customer_Model_Customer && !$customer->isObjectNew()) {

            // check display name is posted
            if(!empty($postData['display_name'])){

                $current_name = $customer->getDisplayName();
                $new_name = $postData['display_name'];

                // duplicate check
                $customer_check = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('display_name')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('display_name',$new_name)->load();

                if ( is_object($customer_check) && count($customer_check) >= 2) {
                    // dont allow - duplicate customer displayname
                }
                else {

                    if( $postData['display_name'] !== $current_name ) {
                        $customer->setDisplayName($postData['display_name']);
                    }

                }

            }

        }

        Mage::register('customer_save_observer_executed',true); 

    }
}
```

but this just updates the display_name even if i deliberately set it to a duplicate of another customers

**UPDATE**

Looking into this further it looks like the module function itself is not being run or nothing inside it is taking affect, as whatever i put in it doesn't work. It is infact the default behaviour that is setting the displayname not my module. My module is activated and my config file uses the `customer_save_commit_after` event as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <xxx_xxxxx>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </xxx_xxxxx>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <xxx_xxxxx>
                <class>xxx_xxxxx_Model</class>
            </xxx_xxxxx>
        </models>
        <events>
            <customer_save_commit_after>
                <observers>
                    <xxx_xxxxx>
                        <class>xxx_xxxxx/observer</class>
                        <method>xxxxxx</method>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                    </xxx_xxxxx>
                </observers>
            </customer_save_commit_after>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

Comment: what's with the "encryption"? anything to hide? you may have a case problem did you declare your module (aka app/etc/modules/Xxx_Xxxxx.xml)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably is the case because all data from the form submitted is set on the customer model in Magento's Customer module (code taken from `Mage_Customer_AccountController`)

```
/**
 * Forgot customer account information page
 */
public function editAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
    $this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');

    $block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('customer_edit');
    if ($block) {
        $block->setRefererUrl($this->_getRefererUrl());
    }
    $data = $this->_getSession()->getCustomerFormData(true);
    $customer = $this->_getSession()->getCustomer();
    if (!empty($data)) {
        $customer->addData($data);
    }
    if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('changepass') == 1) {
        $customer->setChangePassword(1);
    }

    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($this->__('Account Information'));
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('messages')->setEscapeMessageFlag(true);
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

Here addData() is called on the customer model. To prevent this rename your form's input to something temporary, like `<input name="display_name_tmp"/>`, then in your controller do something like

```
public function xxxxxxxx(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    // to stop event being fired twice
    if(Mage::registry('customer_save_observer_executed')){
        return $this;
    }

    $postData = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost();
    $customer = $observer->getCustomer();

    // if updating NOT a new customer
    if($customer instanceof Mage_Customer_Model_Customer && 
       !$customer->isObjectNew()) {

        // check display name is posted
        if(!empty($postData['display_name_tmp'])){

            $current_name = $customer->getDisplayName();
            $new_name = $postData['display_name_tmp'];

            // duplicate check
            $customer_check = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('display_name')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('display_name',$new_name)->load();

            if ( is_object($customer_check) && count($customer_check) >= 2) {
                // dont allow - duplicate customer displayname
            }
            else {

                if( $postData['display_name'] !== $current_name ) {
                    $customer->setDisplayName($postData['display_name_tmp']);
                }

            }

        }

    }

    Mage::register('customer_save_observer_executed',true); 

}
```

Comment: Having tried that and it not working, i have since looked back through the code and it seems nothing in the module's function is being run/used. Am i using the wrong event maybe? I have updated my question with more info

Comment: Are you sure your module is active? For that you need to put a YournameSpace_Yourmodule.xml file in `app/etc/modules` (look at the other files there to get the correct syntax).

Additionally i think the `customer_save_commit_after` event is the wrong one anyway since data has already been saved there. I suggest you use `customer_save_before` instead.

It would also be helpful if you did not replace the real values by "xxx" in your config so we can take a look if there is a mistake in the config itself.

Comment: The module is definitely active. It uses the same setup as a few other custom modules which all work and i can see it enabled in the admin > config > advanced. Do you know what event i should use then? I assume theres not a `before` version of the event?

Comment: There is, use `customer_save_before`. Could you paste the real configuration values so we can take a look at that?

Comment: Using a display_name_tmp and changing to `customer_save_before` has done the trick. Thank you for solving